# node.js / express, request body is null

Tags: sql, node.js, express

learning express and for some reason my request body is NULL for both paramenters

my complete file for index.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
const db = require('./queries')

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  }));

app.get('/',(request, response) => {
    response.json({info: 'express and postgresapi'})
})

app.post('/users', db.createUser)

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App running on port ${port}.`)
  })
```

and my queries file where I am making the POST

```
const Pool = require('pg').Pool
const pool = new Pool({
  user: 'postgres',
  host: 'localhost',
  database: 'chatDb',
  password: 'password1',
  port: 5432,
})

  const createUser = (request, response) => {
    const { name, email } = request.body

console.log(request.query);

pool.query('INSERT INTO users (name, email) VALUES ($1, $2)', [name, email], (error, results) => {
  if (error) {
      console.log(request.body)
    throw error
  }
  response.status(201).send(`User added with ID: ${results.insertId}`)
})
```

}

so this actually DOES post, but when  I look at the rows in my db they are like

```
ID      name    email
20      NULL    NULL
```

my curl is
curl --data "name=Elaine&email=elaine@example.com"
http://localhost:3000/users

also, the outcome of console.log(request.query); is {}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey you need to pass an object if your using postman

```
{
 "name":"your name here",
 "email":"email that you want"
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: wow i actually feel stupid. I am using insomnia as an api checker and that interpolates curls differently, code wasnt the problem it was the client. did this in the body and it worked, im an idiot haha thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are sending request parameters as a params then use -

```
const createUser = (request, response) => {
    const { name, email } = request.query;

pool.query('INSERT INTO users (name, email) VALUES ($1, $2)', [name, email], (error, results) => {
  if (error) {
      console.log(request.body)
    throw error
  }
  response.status(201).send(`User added with ID: ${results.insertId}`)
})
```

2. If you are sending request parameters within the body then use -

```
const createUser = (request, response) => {
    const { name, email } = request.body;

pool.query('INSERT INTO users (name, email) VALUES ($1, $2)', [name, email], (error, results) => {
  if (error) {
      console.log(request.body)
    throw error
  }
  response.status(201).send(`User added with ID: ${results.insertId}`)
})
```

** you can open your postman and you will get two options Params and Body Options. If you select Body then send the request body using  either urlencode or json format because you added body-parser -

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  }));
```